# script-fu multiplication : not enought argument

Tags: gimp, script-fu

simple multiplication is failling in my script-fu.
the folowing code

> ```
>     (print "hello")
>     (print (/ 4 3))
>     (print (* 3 4))
>     (print "world")
> ```

Gives :

> ```
>      "hello"  
>      1,333333333.0  
>      Error: ( : 1) not enough arguments
> ```

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm using Gimp 2.6 on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Patrice, I use gimp 2.8.14-1+b1 on Debian and I've tested your code in the `script-fu` console. No problems. If I were you I'd try to see if your problem has been reported in the bug tracker of your distro.

Comment: These statemetns are simple and unambiguous - this error could be raised by "print" if ana rguemt is missing to it - so probably what is pasted here is nto what you are typing.  Are you just typing these in the script-fuy terminal, or putting statements like this inside a full script? If so, please close this question, and put your real code in a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem when trying to add new functionality to someone else's script. I wanted to provide my solution in case anyone else runs into a similar issue.

In this case, there was a '(let* (...))' statement that was being used to initialize some variables. The original author of the script wrote '(let * (...))' - **with a space between let and star** - which means every vector in the 'let' statement becomes the expected arguments for the '*' statement.

More info: http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/let.html

Please excuse (and correct if necessary) any incorrect nomenclature regarding Scheme. I have barely just been exposed to it.

Comment: Great! I guess the solution can be simplified to '* has been redefined somewhere', and chances are it's a typo at 'let*'.